# Excel 2007 Format Row of Cells containing certain text

Tags: excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to perform conditional formatting in Excel 2007 by checking if a cell has a specific string in it and therefore highlighting the entire row corresponding to the text. However, Excel 2007's Conditional Formatting only allows me to highlight that specific cell. Is there a workaround to this without having to get my hands dirty with VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula is: =IF($G1="matching_string",true,false)
Do this somewhere in row 1, then copy the format everywhere you need it. The
$ sign locks the formula on column G, while the row number is floating.